# Using Sql with Windows Store

Tags: c#, sql, windows-store-apps

I've found a few Google searches on this topic but nothing that really helps me.
Maybe because I don't understand what's happening.

How do I connect my Localdb using WA to a windows store application and how do i get the data from it with C#. Like "SELECT * FROM Table"

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way, you need to create a separate app that provides WCF endpoint that process all requests to the database and returns data to the client in this case this windows store app. You can create a windows service that provides such endpoint and in that service you implement all communication with database and provide API to the WSA(windows store app) through WCF